# Saying something is "for real" vs just saying something is "real"

Tags: grammar, to-for

I have a silly question that's been stuck in my head for a little bit. There was a movie that came out a little while ago called, "Heaven is for real" ... and something about the word "for" in that title bothered me. I've heard the expression several more times about something being "for real" vs just "real" .... what is the point of the word "for" in that context?

Something about the usage of the words "for real" makes me feel like the phrase is trying to convince me (in kind of a common folksy kind of way, almost childlike way) that I should be convinced of somethings "realness". (You might disagree with this...) but some part of me feels like that using the word "for" in "X is for real" is an attempt to manipulate the listener into validating the claim. Is that unfair?

I guess my questions are: What is the proper grammar concerning "X is for real" vs "X is real" ??? And my second question is what is your interpretation of the word "for" in the term "X is for real"... why use the word "for"  in that context?

Comment: I think you're right: it is an expression associated with childish speech, and used more or less consciously for that connotation. In structure, it is similar to _for fun_, but _fun_ is a noun, not an adjective (it has limited adjectival use), so it's not quite parallel.

Comment: "for real" is also used to mean the opposite of "for practice", "for testing", etc.

Comment: I think you're spot-on. Children use this phrase, and the movie/book is based on what a *child (supposedly) said*. @TheBlueDog - anger management courses are really fun. It's amazing how they take down the rage...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*For real* indeed has a kind of slangy/childish connotation, which I'm sure is why it was used in the title of that movie (a quick Google search reveals that the film is about a four-year-old who has a near-death experience).

However, it also does not mean the same thing as *real*: if something is *real*, it **exists**, while if something is *for real*, it is **legitimate**.

Merriam-Webster [backs up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/real) this adjectival sense of *for real* (definition 3.2 and 3.3 at that link):

> 2:  *genuine* "couldn't believe the threats were for real"
>
> 3: *genuinely good or capable of success* "not yet sure if this team is for real"

To be fair, that dictionary also gives *genuine* as one definition of just plain "real", but I do think that "for real" is much *more* about legitimacy than "real", to the point that there is a definite difference in meaning. Consider the following examples (mine, this time):

> A: I don't think this pizza is real.
>
> B: I don't think this pizza is for real.

If I were looking at a plastic replica of a pizza, I could say **A** but not **B**. In contrast, if I had just been given a pizza that I was told was from a famous restaurant, but in fact looked very unappetizing, I could say **B** but not **A**.

Of course I contrived that example to demonstrate the difference in meaning. To return to your original question, *Heaven is real* and *Heaven is for real* do indeed mean pretty much the same thing. But my point was to show that *real* and *for real* are not always interchangeable.

As for the grammar part of your question, I don't think *for real* is grammatically remarkable - there are other structures of the form "[Noun] is for [adjective]", e.g. *This coffee is for free*.

Comment: +1 for legitimate. When someone asks me _Are you for real?_ they are obviously not asking if I am actually real.

Comment: @Frank, that's a great and much simpler illustration of what I was trying to say! Thanks.

Comment: *For real* can also be used in contexts where it means ***serious*** (as opposed to either or both senses - *flippant, in jest* and *inconsequential, trivial*).

Comment: Could you give me an example of when "for real" can be interpreted as "serious" ?

Comment: @Greg **I drunk eight bottles of vodka last night** _Are you for real?_ **No, I'm joking, it was ten**. Change _for real_ to _serious_ and there you have it.

Comment: @Frank "I drank" not "I drunk".

Comment: @Doc After ten bottles of vodka I think one can be excused for a little grammar slippage. ;)

Comment: @Greg - "This isn't some stupid movie stunt you're pulling; this is *for real*. People can get hurt."

Comment: I have never heard anyone use for real in the context of B. That sounds like the pizza is talking or has done something unbelievable.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely slang. But I believe it is more synonymous with *serious*, or *seriously*...

> "Is he for real?"

or

> Person A: "I just jumped over that garbage can."
> Person B: "For real?"

It is simple, if you are using this specific slang you are probably in a very informal setting.

Answer (score 2):

Here, *for* seems to be being used as a kind of intensifier, a marker to increase the rhetorical weight of the word *real.*

In other words, it does not merely state the purported fact of the realness/reality of Heaven, it positively tries to assert it.

As far as I can see, it doesn't have any genuinely *grammatical* function when used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

"For real" is grammatically incorrect as is "For free", as 'real' and 'free', not being nouns or pronouns, cannot be used with prepositions such as 'for'. The grammatical incorrectness of this usage is not mitigated by the fact that the usage is widely and commonly prevalent. What is intended to be conveyed with the inclusion of "For" can be conveyed correctly with just "Real", "Really" and "Free". Thus, "For" is both an inappropriate and unnecessary interloper.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a manipulation, nor an attempt to convince a listener of something but just conversational slang. Interestingly,  it is both used as by someone who is telling and listening:

**speaker**: 'I bought this for ten buck -for real'

**listener**: Ten bucks! For real! Cool bro!

Comment: Of course it's [in your example] an attempt to convince. It's the conversational version of the veridical (ie commenting on the truth of a statement) pragmatic marker _Really_ !

Comment: It really is just a slangy reply that is oft-repeated in conversation -rather like the 60s(?) equivalent to 'cool' -an approval

Comment: alcas disagrees. Google disagrees: **for real**
phrase 
1.
informal
used to assert that something is genuine or is actually the case.
"I'm not playing games — this is for real!" I disagree.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the **listener** case it's expressing mild doubt or soliciting confirmation while all the time accepting that the **speaker** is telling the truth. (it should have a question mark really). Or alternately it could be expressing joy towards the **speakers** good fortune, then it wouldn't need a question mark. It's a very flexible term, that's for sure.

Comment: @EdwimAshworth That would be the 'expressing joy and delight' version. _That is for real_ in Third News' answer.

Comment: @Frank Yes; it's indeed flexible, as with many of the (especially informal) pragmatic markers. But OP asks about "X is for real", not "X is for real?": 'saying something is for real'. The usage given at 'Urban Dictionary' (= 'You're not kidding!'; perhaps even grading into Third News' 'How about that!' / 'You don't say!') is another one not appropriate here. 'Answers' are to be addressed to what the OP is actually asking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe I've misunderstood the OP. I felt that he meant he knew how _for real_ was used in _Heaven is for real_ and was asking for what it meant in _X is for real_ which opens up a wide range of possibilities including things like _Kim Kardashians bottom is for real_ and your own _I'm not playing games - this is for real_ and also _Are you for real?_.

Comment: @Frank I think you got to the heart of what's bothering me about the context of "Heaven is for real" ... it's the simultaneous soliciting of confirmation from the listener while asserting itself as a truth from the speaker that bothers me. The flexibility of the language feels crafty and manipulative to me, possibly pandering to the listeners biases for support. I know it's just a movie title but I don't like how the title pins down the listener into accepting the premise just by its own assertion. I'm curious about the demographic for which that title is particularly effective for.

Comment: @Greg I don't really get the "manipulative" sense you do from the title at all, or why you feel it "pins down the listener". I'm pretty sure that (as I said in my answer) that is the title because it is an expression that can sound childish, and the person experiencing heaven in the story is a four-year-old boy.